# Erro ao compilar arquivos no rmarkdown

Tags: r

Recentemente atualizei o Ubuntu em meu computador, continuei usando normalmente o R, inclusive o rmarkdown. Hoje fui compilar uma arquivo que já tinha compilado anteriormente e apareceu o seguinte erro:

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  impossível carregar objeto compartilhado '/home/amanda/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  libicui18n.so.55: não é possível abrir arquivo compartilhado: Arquivo ou diretório inexistente
Calls: :: ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execução interrompida
```

Tentei rodar outros códigos, e nenhum deu, sempre com este mesmo problema, e em nenhum formato, nem word, nem html, nem pdf. Nem mesmo aquele código base que vem assim que abrimos o rmarkdown quer rodar.

Alguém já teve este problema, e sabe como resolver? Será que tem alguma relação com as atualizações feitas recentemente? Não consigo me lembrar se utilizei o rmarkdown depois de ter atualizado.

Comment: Tente reinstalar o package `stringi`: `install.packages('stringi')`.

Comment: Reinstalei. Mas continuei tendo erros

Comment: agora apresenta o seguinte erro:    pandoc: loadlocale.c:130: _nl_intern_locale_data: Assertion `cnt < (sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME) / sizeof (_nl_value_type_LC_TIME[0]))' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
Error in strsplit(version_info, "\n")[[1]] : índice fora de limites
Calls: <Anonymous> ... pandoc_available -> find_pandoc -> lapply -> FUN -> get_pandoc_version
Além disso: Warning message:
execução do comando ''/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc' --version' teve status 134 
Execução interrompida

Comment: Ao compilar linha a linha dentro do próprio `Rmd` tudo roda certinho? Se sim, acredito que o erro no Rmarkdown deve ser um pouco mais interpretável. Eu recentemente passei o meu PC do Ubuntu 16.04 para 18.04 de forma automática (sugestão do sistema), e não tive problemas.